# XSS attack - by initiating the url using URL class

Tags: java, tomcat, url

I built a web application which simply prints the name of user, run it on browser, and checked XSS attack. I can see a pop up which means my application is vulnerable to XSS attacks. Url entered in browser -
`http://localhost/users?name=<script>alert("hi")</script>`

I then used the URL class to send the request `url.openConnection()`. Now since the url contains script tag which should get run inside the server and the server should return me an unexpected response. But it isn't. Name gets printed as `script>alert("hi")</script>`.

My question is, if the code was vulnerable then why did it printed the name as entered. What should be the expected response?

**EDIT**:
Steps I perform -

1. I programmatically start the Tomcat server (using Tomcat library).

   `Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();`
2. I deploy a servlet which I want to test for XSS.

   `Tomcat.addServlet(context, servletName, Servlet)
   //Tomcat.addServlet(ctx, User, src.main.java.User`
3. I use URL class to get the response from the servlet.

`HTTPUrlConnection con = new URL("http://myURL").openConnection();`

Comment: What do you mean, what is the actual issue? Do you want to secure your site from XSS attack?

Comment: post pre and after code

Comment: @Ankit, I want to test my code against XSS vulnerability. See edited question.